# How to filter a Dataframe based on an ID-Column which corresponds to a second Dataframe containing conditions for each ID efficiently?

Tags: pandas, performance, dataframe, filter, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe with one ID column and two data columns X,Y containing numeric values. For each ID there are several rows of data.

I have a second Dataframe with the same ID column and two numeric columns specifing the lower and upper Limit for the X - Values for each ID.

I want to use the second Dataframe to filter the first Dataframe to only have rows which have X Values within in the X_min-X_max Range of the specific ID.

I can solve this by Looping over the second dataframe and filtering groupby(ID) - Elements of the first DF but that is slow for large amount of IDs. Is there an efficient way to solve this?

Example Code with the data in df, the ranges in df_ranges and the expected result in df_result. The real data Frame is obviously a lot bigger.

```
import pandas as pd

x=[2.1,2.2,2.6,2.4,2.8,3.5,2.8,3.2]
y=[3.1,3.5,3.4,2.7,2.1,2.7,4.1,4.3]
ID=[0]*4+[0.1]*4
x_min=[2.0,3.0]
x_max=[2.5,3.4]
IDs=[0,0.1]
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':ID,'X':x,'Y':y})
df_ranges=pd.DataFrame({'ID':IDs,'X_min':x_min,'X_max':x_max})
df_result=df.iloc[[0,1,3,7],:]
```

Possible Solution:

```
def filter_ranges(grp,df_ranges):
    x_min=df_ranges.loc[df_ranges.ID==grp.name,'X_min'].values[0]
    x_max=df_ranges.loc[df_ranges.ID==grp.name,'X_max'].values[0]
    return grp.loc[(grp.X>=x_min)&(grp.X<=x_max),:]

target_df_grp=df.groupby('ID').apply(filter_ranges,df_ranges=df_ranges)
```

Comment: Can you post sample input and expected output?

Comment: Check answer and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
merged = df.merge(df_ranges, on='ID')
target_df = merged[(merged.X>=merged.X_min)&(merged.X<=merged.X_max)][['ID', 'X', 'Y']]  # Here, desired filter is applied.
```

`print(target_df)` will give:

```
 ID    X    Y
0  0.0  2.1  3.1
1  0.0  2.2  3.5
3  0.0  2.4  2.7
7  0.1  3.2  4.3
```

Comment: How does your solution compare to my edit in Terms of Efficiency?

Comment: One way of looking at it is, your solution is using `apply()` and essentially it iterates over each group. Whereas, this solution does not require any explicit iterations which means it is vectorised solution.